# Pygame's pygame.event.get()'s key value is a ridiculous number as of today, why?

Tags: python, pygame

My program used to run the following bit of code and it worked perfectly when i pressed left shift. But as of today it suddenly stopped working, no code changed, no reinstalls, no updates since it was working and stopped working.

```
#running on windows 10
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            print(event)
            if event.key == 304:#left shift
                print("worked")
```

the output of print(event) used to be :

> <Event(768-KeyDown {'unicode': '', 'key': 304, 'mod': 4096,
> 'scancode': 79, 'window': None})> now it is : <Event(768-KeyDown
> {'unicode': '', 'key': 1073742049, 'mod': 4096, 'scancode': 79,
> 'window': None})>

I know how to fix it, or do it in a different way, but does someone know the reason the `'key'` is suddenly a ridiculous number? Is there something wrong with my computer that the key values it's giving is messed up?

Comment: In hex, that's 0x400000E1.  There are probably flags in the high-order bits.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you didn`t write the key codes on your own. It will be better if you use the predefined pygame key, for example:

```py
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            print(event)
            if event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
                print("worked")
```

Here is a list of pygame`s predefined keys.

[pygame documentation - pygame.key](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use `pygame.K_LEFT` if you want to detect if <kbd>LEFT</kbd> is pressed.

Let me refer to the documentation of the [`pygame.key`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) module:

> Portability note: The integers for key constants differ between pygame 1 and 2. Always use key constants (`K_a`) rather than integers directly (97) so that your key handling code works well on both pygame 1 and pygame 2.

A user friendly name of a key can be get by [`pygame.key.name()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.name):

> Get the descriptive name of the button from a keyboard button id constant.

The keyboard events `KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP` (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) create a [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object with additional attributes. The key that was pressed can be obtained from the `key` attribute. The `unicode` attribute provides the Unicode representation of the keyboard input.

Answer (score 0):

You have num-lock enabled.

With `num-lock` enabled, `event.mod` is `4096` instead of `0` (`pygame.KMOD_NONE`)